# Can PA prove very fast growing functions to be total?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, proof-theory

The Goodstein-sequence is a total function, but PA cannot prove this.

Is this true for any other function with growth rate at least $f_{\epsilon_0}$
 or are there functions growing at least as fast as the Goodstein-sequence that
 PA can prove to be total ?

I heard that the "power" of the PA is below the $f_{\epsilon_0}$-level, but I do
 not know if this answers my question.

Comment: This is the first question I've seen correctly tagged with [proof-theory] in a very long time. It makes me sad to realize how often I have to remove this tag, and even sadder that I'm happy not to remove it here.

Comment: Thanks for this compliment.

Comment: You can find some discussion in the final half of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/625404/242) and its links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every function which eventually outgrows $f_{\varepsilon_0}$ cannot be proven to be total in Peano arithmetic. This is implied by more general result:

> PA can prove a computable function $F$ to be total if and only if $F$ is primitively recursive in $f_{\omega\uparrow\uparrow n}$ for some finite $n$, where $\omega\uparrow\uparrow n=\omega^{...^\omega}$ with $\omega$ $n$ times.

In particular, if $F$ outgrows all of $f_{\omega\uparrow\uparrow n}$ for finite $n$, then PA cannot prove $F$ total.

[Reference](http://cage.ugent.be/~weierman/bsl.pdf)

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: Do you also know the limit for ZFC ?

Comment: The result I mentioned is related to the fact that $\varepsilon_0$ is so called proof theoretic ordinal of PA. For similar result for ZFC we would need ordinal which is at least its proof theoretic ordinal, which is far beyond the reach of all known notations. Even then, we are not guaranteed such classification exists.

Comment: I have heard of the growing rate $\Gamma_0$, for example, it would be interesting if ZFC can handle this stuff.

Comment: @Peter: To quote an over quoted movie, "that escalated quickly"!

Comment: @Peter ZFC can actually handle fast growing hierarchy up to $\Gamma_0$ (a.k.a. Feferman-Schutte ordinal).

Comment: Wow, so ZFC is really strong! Thanks again.

Comment: @Peter In fact, the proof theoretic ordinal of ZFC is much, much larger than $\Gamma_0$. Even the Takeuti-Feferman-Buchholz ordinal $\psi(\varepsilon_{\Omega_\omega+1})$ is not coming close. Nor is the proof theoretic ordinal of KPI, which is even larger. The comparison of these ordinals with the proof theoretic ordinal of ZFC is like the comparison of a googolplex with Graham's number, to put it *mildly*.