# Interesting examples of first-order, one-sorted proper extensions of PA

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Are there any interesting nontrivial examples of [first-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), [one-sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic) theories *of [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number)* (i.e. theories whose [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) range over natural numbers *only* and not, say, sets of natural numbers) that are stronger than first-order [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) (PA)?

PA is usually strengthened by introducing sets of natural numbers (e.g. [second-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) and its [subsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics)) or working with sets of sets (e.g. various [set theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)).

Simply adding lengthy, complex [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich%27s_theorem) that express the [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency) of PA or stronger theories is an example of what I'm *not* looking for, since it fails the interestingness criterion and is aesthetically ad-hoc from an axiomatic standpoint.

Comment: There are "natural" statements about $\mathbb{N}$ that $\mathsf{PA}$ doesn't prove. One famous example is the [Paris-Harrington Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) in ramsey theory. Would $\mathsf{PA} + \text{"Paris-Harrington is True"}$ be an "interesting example" from your point of view?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor That's certainly less ad-hoc, though I was hoping for an axiomatic system that is more "internally cohensive", "minimal" in assumptions, and "maximal" in consequences, like PA itself. These are of course informal notions, and I'm not sure how to formalize them, but hopefully you can sense what I mean. Is there perhaps an especially concise statement that entails PH?

Comment: In their [original paper](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/ph.pdf), Paris and Harrington prove that (over PA) this combinatorial fact is equivalent to "For all $\Sigma^0_1$ formulas $\varphi$, if $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \varphi$, then $\varphi$ is true" (a property called "$\Sigma^0_1$ reflection"). This is stronger than $\text{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, so it's not a theorem of $\mathsf{PA}$. This is snappy, but I don't think it's what you're looking for

Comment: You might be interested in [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics), which takes very weak systems as the default, and tries to figure out _precisely_ how strong "typical" theorems in mathematics are. In particular, [$\mathsf{ACA}_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Arithmetical_comprehension_ACA0) is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{PA}$ and much is known about what happens when you add bonus axioms to it. Though it's _not_ first order, so again, it's not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: One example of a "natural" strengthening of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is the [perfect set theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property). It's known that over $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ this is equivalent to [$\mathsf{ATR_0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Arithmetical_transfinite_recursion_ATR0), which proves the consistency of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, so adding the perfect set theorem (erm... perfect set axiom?) to $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ makes the proof theory strictly stronger.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Wouldn't talking about things like $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \varphi$ and perfect sets require lots of encoding? I don't see a concise way to axiomatize them in the language of natural numbers.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Quibble: $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ *is* first-order (despite the term "second-order arithmetic" being used in its context), but it's two-sorted.

Comment: @NoahSchweber -- Quibble internalized! I'm far from an expert on reverse mathematics, so I appreciate the correction ^_^

Comment: And @user76284, yes, there's lots of coding required in both of those statements. That's one of the reasons I thought you might be dissatisfied with them as potential answers.

Comment: One idea that I had before that is not quite as ad-hoc as consistency/soundness statements is [a semi-recursive ω-rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2456919/21820), which @NoahSchweber partially answered.

Answer (score 3):

There are now several examples known of interesting arithmetical sentences independent of $\mathsf{PA}$ (e.g. Paris-Harrington), and any of these - when added to $\mathsf{PA}$ as an axiom - gives of course a proper strengthening of $\mathsf{PA}$ in the same language. However, even if we're totally convinced of the interestingness of such axioms, the fact remains that such extensions may feel ad hoc.

Another approach we could take is to take an existing theory $T$ of interest in a richer language, and look at the theory $T'$ consisting of $T$'s arithmetical consequences. For example, the set of arithmetical consequences of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a computably axiomatizable first-order theory in the language of arithmetic which properly extends $\mathsf{PA}$. However, this may still feel like a cheat; moreover, we often lack a good way to describe the resulting $T'$ "on its own terms" (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989762/is-there-a-nice-axiomatization-in-the-language-of-arithmetic-of-the-statements/1992395#1992395)).

Ultimately, it's difficult to get away from the conclusion that $\mathsf{PA}$ is a fairly natural "stopping point." I find this fascinating, and am interested in any results supporting or attacking this (admittedly *extremely* informal) idea. For now, the only thing that comes to mind is, interestingly enough, a positive result - that is, attacking the idea of $\mathsf{PA}$-uniqueness - which came as a surprise to me: we can produce proper **first-order** extensions of $\mathsf{PA}$ in the language of arithmetic using the same "core idea" that motivated $\mathsf{PA}$ itself by bringing strong-but-not-*too*-strong natural logics into play.

Specifically, suppose I have a logic $\mathcal{L}$ (e.g. first-order logic, second-order logic, etc.). We can define a **first-order** theory $\mathsf{PA}[\mathcal{L}]$ as follows: it consists of all first-order consequences of the $\mathcal{L}$-theory gotten from $\mathsf{PA}$ by extending the induction scheme to range over $\mathcal{L}$-formulas. Note that although we're going through a non-first-order logic $\mathcal{L}$, we do wind up with a first-order theory in the end: $\mathsf{PA}[\mathcal{L}]$ is the "first-order part" of an $\mathcal{L}$-theory.

A quick perusal of the abstract model theory literature may suggest - or at least it suggested to me at one point - that the situation is uninteresting: that for every "natural" logic $\mathcal{L}$ extending first-order logic, we either have $\mathsf{PA}[\mathcal{L}]=\mathsf{PA}$ or $\mathsf{PA}[\mathcal{L}]=Th(\mathbb{N})$. However, **this turns out not to be the case** as [the answers to this MathOverflow question of mine showed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385413/how-special-is-first-order-mathsfpa).

Of particular note is what I'll call $\mathsf{PA}[\mathit{Ramsey}]$; this is what we get when we apply the above idea to the extension of $\mathsf{FOL}$ gotten by adding Ramsey (or Magidor-Malitz) quantifiers. The resulting theory turns out to be ... [**precisely the arithmetical fragment of the first-order theory $\Pi^1_1$-$\mathsf{CA_0}$!**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273152) So not only do we have a proper first-order strengthening of $\mathsf{PA}$ in the same language which is computably axiomatizable and motivated by a coherent "core idea" (the same as $\mathsf{PA}$ itself, together with the basic motivation for generalized quantifiers), but we *also* have a connection with an existing theory of interest in a different setting. And this in turn should make us more interested in the $T\leadsto T'$-construction I dismissed a few paragraphs prior:

> Maybe the arithmetical parts of strong first-order theories correspond, at least sometimes, to "$\mathsf{PA}$-analogues" for logics extending $\mathsf{FOL}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Ramsey quantifier idea sounds interesting. Does it have natural deduction style introduction and elimination rules? (I think the condition that $a \neq a'$ can be dropped from the quantifier definition without loss of power.) I also wonder if the 3 introduced axiom schemes can be simplified somewhat. Finally, I had the same thought regarding PA seeming like a natural stopping point in terms of minimality vs. power, though I'm not aware of results regarding that.

Comment: What about adding [a fast growing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1080936/76284)?

Comment: @user76284 I presume you mean adding an axiom asserting that a particular fast-growing function is total? To me that seems no less ad hoc than adding consistency statements or similar. But at this point things get subjective. As to your earlier comment (sorry, I just saw it!), I don't know much about Ramsey logic; that might be worth asking as a separate MSE question.