# What is this operator called?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, arithmetic, tetration

If $x \cdot 2 = x + x$

and $x \cdot 3 = x + x + x$

and $x^2 = x \cdot x$

and $x^3 = x \cdot x \cdot x$

Is there an operator $\oplus$ such that:

$x \oplus 2 = x^x$

and $x \oplus 3 = {x^{x^x}}$?

Also, is there a name for such a set of operators ops where...

Ops(1) is addition

Ops(2) is multiplication

Ops(3) is exponentiation

Ops(4) is $\oplus$

...and so on

Also, is there a branch of math who actually deals with such questions? Have these questions already been answered like 2000 years ago?

Comment: You may be interested in [the Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). Makes for fun problems in recursion theory and such.

Comment: FYI  $(x^x)^x = x^{(x^2)} \ne x^{(x^x)}$ so the operation is not associative so the notation ${x^x}^x$ is ambiguous.  We usually take it to mean $x^{(x^x)}$ because $(((x^x)^x)^x).... = x^{(x^m)}$ and can be expressed that way.

Comment: Also of note: the "Ops" are known as [Hyperoperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation).

Comment: i think fleablood got the convention backward.  $a^{b^c}$ is understood as $a^{(b^c)}$ because $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This operation  ${\rm Ops}(4)$ is called [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), from the greek root *tetra* meaning four; it's also sometimes called a "power tower". There are also many further generalizations of this type of sequence; [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) gives $a^{a^{a^a}}=a\uparrow\uparrow4$, so that $a\uparrow\uparrow n$ is the tetration operation. By adding more arrows you get pentation and so on, and the [Conway chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) generalizes this still further.

FYI, for "to the power of-ation" the word you're looking for is [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Comment: Also that is similar to graham number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number

Comment: Aha, and the answer to the second question is hyperoperation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation

Comment: Ah, the whims of the internet. This does not deserve to be my highest-voted answer.

Comment: It's the bikeshed, Mario; you get used to it.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that a↑↑n is not defined to be tetration operation. It is a consequence of a↑n being defined as $a^n$ and then further arrows is defined to be n number of iterations of itself minus one arrow on a. Much prefer @Curd 's answer

Comment: @ArianaGrande It follows exactly the same definitional scheme as the OP used. Also I don't understand the distinction you are making - they have exactly the same expansion, only the notation is different. Anyway I'm not judging which is the "best" here, just giving some links to further information.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro If you are complaining, I'll just give you a high five without any upvote.

Comment: @Simply Or you could upvote one of my other posts in its stead! ;)

Answer (score 9):

A more general function that combines all those operators has been defined by [Ackermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function):

$
\varphi(m,n,p) = \begin{cases}
\varphi(m, n, 0) = m + n \\
\varphi(m, 0, 1) = 0 \\
\varphi(m, 0, 2) = 1 \\
\varphi(m, 0, p) = m &\text{ for } p > 2 \\
\varphi(m, n, p) = \varphi(m, \varphi(m, n-1, p), p - 1) &\text{ for } n > 0 \text{ and } p > 0.
\end{cases}
$

So for $p = 0, 1, 2$ you get

$\phi(m, n, 0) = m + n $
$\phi(m, n, 1) = m \cdot n $
$\phi(m, n, 2) = m ^ n $

and

$\phi(m, n, 3) = \overbrace{{{m ^ m} ^ m} ^ {...}}^{n}$

Comment: More generally see [fast growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy). You can find an introduction to some of these topics in the articles cited in my post on [Goodstein's Theorem.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/625404/242)

Answer (score 9):

It is known as a tetration, and it is normally written as $^na$ where n is the height of the power tower. It is the forth hyperoperation.

The zeroth hyperoperation is the successor function, and the first is the zeroth hyperoperation iterated, and so on

A more general way to define the nth hyperoperation is, using the notation, $H_n(a,b)$ where n is the nth hyperoperation,

${\displaystyle H_{n}(a,b)={\begin{cases}b+1&{\text{if }}n=0\\a&{\text{if }}n=1{\text{ and }}b=0\\0&{\text{if }}n=2{\text{ and }}b=0\\1&{\text{if }}n\geq 3{\text{ and }}b=0\\H_{n-1}(a,H_{n}(a,b-1))&{\text{if }n\in\mathbb{N},n>3}\end{cases}}}$

Some notations for hyperoperations are(for $H_n(a,b)$:

1. Square bracket notation: $a[n]b$
2. Box notation: $a{\,{\begin{array}{|c|}\hline {\!n\!}\\\hline \end{array}}\,}b$
3. Nambiar's notation  : $a\otimes ^{n-1}b$
4. Knuth's up arrow notation: $a\uparrow^{n-2}b$
5. Goodstien's notation: $G(a,b,n)$
6. Conway's chained arrow notation: $a\rightarrow b\rightarrow (n-2)$
7. Bowers exploding array function: $\{a,b,n,1\}$
8. Original Ackermann function: ${\begin{matrix}\phi (a,b,n-1)\ {\text{ for }}1\leq n\leq 3\\\phi (a,b-1,n-1)\ {\text{ for }}n\geq 4\end{matrix}}$

Comment: Wow, Arianna Grande as a mathematician and stackexchange user. Exciting,

Comment: @Cheskos Ariana

Comment: Is any of these 8 extending Peter Hurfords [$C(a,\dots)$](https://archive.is/rEzX6) (see Extending the Extensions)?

Comment: @R_Berger The extension, I believe, grows faster than every function in the 8 listed